# Why does my stored procedure ignore alter constraints when called from ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, constraints

So I have a stored procedure that does the following (modified out the data params):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ReceiptInfo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT Credits_ReceiptInfo_FK1;
UPDATE ReceiptInfo SET CreditAccount=@CreditAccount WHERE  CreditAccount=@OriginalAccount;
ALTER TABLE dbo.ReceiptInfo CHECK CONSTRAINT Credits_ReceiptInfo_FK1;
```

This is all in a stored procedure, which runs perfectly fine when I execute it from management studio but skips the alter constraints when called from ASP.net.  I know it's at least executing the stored proc, because I get a message saying the update conflicted with the constraint.

For the record, I know this could all be solved by ON UPDATE CASCADE, but that option was rejected by upper management.

Comment: You're definitely calling that exact stored procedure and not either a different one or worse some inline SQL in the code that should be pointing at the proc? There shouldn't be any difference running the procedure from management studio and ASP.NET...

Comment: Are they the only lines of the procedure?  If so, wouldn't the second alter always throw an error?

Comment: Could be a permissions problem for the account under which this is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Management Studio to execute a stored procedure, that is done under your account that presumably has admin rights.

When you execute the sp from asp.net, you probably use another account, that is not allowed to do this.

Comment: Integrated Security is set to true, so presumably they're both going through my Windows account.  I'll double check to make sure.  But still, wouldn't that make the whole stored proc a bust, and not just parts of it?  Or will it keeping charging through until it finds something within its permissions?

Comment: Not if the account has rights to execute the procedure, but no Alter permissions. So yes, @Hans Kesting answer seems very likely.

Comment: I thought integrated security=true used my Windows Account?  The same Windows Account that's being used in management studio to successfully run the stored proc.

Edit: Just checked it in Server Profiler, both ASP.net and management studio are run using the same login information.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the problem.  This stored proc actually works fine, it's the one before it that was messed up.  The problem being that the previous stored proc would only throw an error if under the same conditions under which this stored proc would be run.  If it lacks an entry in the child table, it doesn't throw an error.

Sorry for wasting your time.